# Create an non editable PDF file that it is able to accept digital signing using ITextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm currently using this method to encrypt my pdf data. It works just fine on making the pdf a readonly file and it also says that it allows digital signing. However when im trying to sign i get
this error which makes absolute sense.

The creation of new signatures is not permitted in the current document. Reason :

> PDF Permissions dictionary does not allow modification or creation
> interactive form fields, including signature fields when document is
> open with user-access!

My question is if it's possible to create a pdf that is non editable so i can give it to my customers, but they will be able to digital sign it online without changing it contents.

```
        private byte[] EncryptPdfData(byte[] pdfData)
        {
            // Create a memory stream to work with the PDF data
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Create a PdfReader to read the existing PDF data
                using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfData))
                {
                    // Create a PdfStamper to modify the PDF
                    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms))
                    {
                        // Set encryption options
                        stamper.SetEncryption(null, // User password (empty means no password)
                                              null, // Owner password (empty means no password)
                                              PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING | PdfWriter.ALLOW_MODIFY_ANNOTATIONS, // Permissions (allow printing and modify annotations)
                                              PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128); // Encryption strength

                        // Ensure the changes are applied
                        stamper.Close();
                    }
                }

                // Return the encrypted PDF data
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not editable"? Any PDF can be edited somehow.

Comment: Post a link to the encrypted PDF file to take a look at it. I assume @serbian_warrior has a PDF form and he wants to disable the editing of the form fields except for the signature field. This is not possible because the document permissions do not make a difference between form fields. You have to make the form fields you do not want to edit to be read-only. As for the error, as I said, please post a link to the encrypted PDF form.

Comment: @iPDFdev yes, quite likely that is true. But it's also possible that the OP is not aware that Acrobat is one of the few softwares that care about the permissions. Thus, better to ask them what they mean.

Comment: My app generates some PDFs from MS Report Builder. Those pdfs are contracts for my clients. Therefore when a client receives a contract , he should not be able to open it with acrobat and start editing fields. The only thing he should be able to do is to digitally sign the contract and send it back to me.

Comment: If indeed you merely don't want Adobe Acrobat to edit the PDF, you can work with permissions. Have you tried flattening the form, and then adding an empty signature field and encrypting?

Answer (score 1):

I think the OP is talking about PDF permissions which are defined in the PDFSpec as 'user access permissions'. Sure by using tools which ignore those (or any other hacks) it is possible to edit a file. But that was not the question.

[image]

The source code makes it obvious:

```
// Set encryption options
stamper.SetEncryption(null, // User password (empty means no password)
                      null, // Owner password (empty means no password)
                      PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING | PdfWriter.ALLOW_MODIFY_ANNOTATIONS, // Permissions (allow printing and modify annotations)
                      PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128); // Encryption strength
```

I think you need to change the permissions from `ALLOW_MODIFY_ANNOTATIONS -> PdfWriter.ALLOW_FILL_IN`

```
stamper.SetEncryption(null, // User password (empty means no password)
                      null, // Owner password (empty means no password)
                      PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING | PdfWriter.ALLOW_FILL_IN, // Permissions (allow printing and allow signing)
                      PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128); // Encryption strength
```

There are of course other possibilities like setting all non-signature form fields to read-only or flatten the whole PDF except for signature fields. This depends on your exact definition of "read-only". Does it mean 'not being able to modify its content" or to "not being able to fill in forms or to add new form fields" etc.

One additional note:
You are not setting any password. So "*empty means no password*" is correct for the userPassword however not for the owner password. For this one later some random value (hashsum of the createDocumentID method) will be used. So there is always a password just not one you'll know. But if you do not need it that is ok.

```
if (ownerPassword == null || ownerPassword.length == 0)
        ownerPassword = md5.digest(createDocumentId());
```

Comment: *"hashsum of the document ID"* - well, _of a value that could otherwise have become a document ID_. But as the value is used differently here, it's not the document ID.

Comment: correct - it is just the hash of a random value...